# How can I get only '_source' field in elasticsearch client search function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I'm doing elasticsearch in node js. Through 'client.search', I can get data from elasticsearch, but I just want to get '_source' field. How can I do this??

Through javascript 'map' function, I can get only _source data.
However, I want to know what is the body option in 'client.search' to get only source data.

This is my code that is used map function.

```
    index: 'bank',
    body:{
      query:{
        "bool":{
          "must":{"match":{"state":"AL"}}
        }
      }
    }
  }, function getMore(err,data){
    if(err)
    {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    var source = data.hits.hits.map(function(obj){
      return obj._source;
    });
    console.log(source);
    res.end(source);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

With `client.search()` there's no other way.

However, when retrieving a single document, you can use [`client.getSource()`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_getsource) instead of [`client.get()`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_get).

Comment: Hi Val! Thanks for answering!! I see..!!